# Database migrations in database but not in Database\Migrations folder

Tags: laravel, database, migration, laravel-migrations

If there are rows in a migrations table in my database but the migration files are not in the code itself. Would that mean that the people before me who built the code before i took it over never pushed the migrations to the git repo? also if this is true would i have to create my own versions of the migrations and add them to the repo?

Comment: There are many reasons why is this happening... 1. The `database/migrations` are on `.gitignore`; 2. Initially they have migration files but someone deleted it for a reason. In order to know this you have to ask the developer who last coded this or do a `git log database/migrations` on your terminal

Comment: So this is what im thinking. Since i don't have access to the current person who coded this and the main database already has these migrations. All i need to do is pull down the prod db again and then it should be fine to run my new migrations? I'm gonna try this now but i just wanted to ask.

Comment: I actually figured out what i needed do to. There was one other migration than mines in the migration folder. I needed to remove the table added by that migration then i was able to run the migrate command with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, however I would check the packages you are using as well. Sometimes packages allow you to run migrations but they are not registered in your migrations directory.  I always try to publish them to avoid situations like this.  However if you look and don't see any of the missing tables, there are tools are out there that should help you make the migrations from an existing DB.  You can take a look at this package for example: https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator

Comment: well since i see one migration im thinking there should be the other 3. Maybe they deleted them since the prod DB already has the changes. IM checking this out now so ill let you know